# Is this a common romanization style for Korean?

Tags: korean, romanization

I recently saw [an article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41913347?seq=1) that employed an interesting type of romanization of Korean. Here is an example:

[image]

It looks like a mix of Revised Romanization and Yale that replaces digraphs like `eo` or `ng` with IPA-like characters, but I couldn't find this type of romanization listed anywhere. Is this an established system and if so what is it called?

Comment: To me this looks like mostly just IPA (with y replacing j, which is common in some traditions).

Comment: But it's not transcribing the pronunciation.. It is still a transliteration that is independent from phonetic reality (e.g. 'mos' for 못, 'c' for ㅈ).

Comment: Might be phonemic / phonological (i.e. sound-systematic) instead of phonetic (i.e. true to surface sounds). Indistinguishable from the short excerpt, it might also be a transliteration (i.e. a bijective rendering of one script into another).

Comment: As I've mentioned, I am pretty sure it's a transliteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the first time I've seen it, and it seems idiosyncratic. It appears to be a morphophonemic transcription based on [Yale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yale_romanization_of_Korean), as you can see from the way 못하지 is transcribed `mos.ha.ci`.

Other similarities between this system and Yale are evident in the consonants, e.g. using <**k, kk, k<sup>h</sup>**> rather than <g/k, kk, k> for ㄱㄲㅋ. It follows most romanisations in the treatment of orthographic iotated vowels (use of <**y**>) and the majority of orthographic compound vowels (use of <**w**>).

The difference from Yale is evident in the vowels. 먹으면 is transcribed `meg.u.myen` in Yale, but here, ㅓ is mapped to <**ɔ**> and ㅡ to <**ɨ**>. There is some inconsistency in how ㄹ is transcribed here: I see <**l**> for 이런, but <**r**> in 기다려도; Yale uses `l` consistently. Likely to be a typo though.

Comment: As for the L vs R thing, it could depend on whether it's at the syllable onset or in the coda

Comment: @OmarL it would be, except 이런 and 기다려도 are _both_ syllable onset ㄹ, and thus would be treated identically by normal transliteration schemes. For reference, this transliteration scheme uses <l> for 필요.